# how to stop loading each time when i change view from listview to gridview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-gridview

I have Two buttons 1) listview and 2) gridview:

By default i have the listview view and for list i have fetch all records using `AsyncTask` method in which i have bind adapter:

```
adapter = new CategoryAdapter(context, item_name);
```

Now when i change the view from list view to gridview then it is loading and again fetching data with using `AsyncTask` method.

So i don't want to load data again and again when i am changing view from list to grid or grid to list.

For example currently all e-commerce application have this concept. When we change the view from listview to grid or grid to listview it is not loading data again. It is just convert that listview to gridview.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Consider like you has a `List<Objects>` to be loaded to `ListView`. Now you click Grid Button. Pass the same `List<Objects>` to the `GridAdapter` instead of calling `AsyncTask`!

Comment: ok..what about when i am changing the gridview to listview ?

Comment: Reuse the same `List<Objects>` you used for GridView. I think it's not so complicated.

Comment: ok. let me try this.

Answer (score 0):

Preserve your list of records that you got form the `AsyncTask` and when grid button gets clicked feed this list of records to your `GridAdapter`. no need to run `AsyncTask` again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the newly introduced `RecyclerView` component. It has the ability to present the data in different ways - list, grid or something custom using a `LayoutManager` instance. Try something like this:

```
// Shows the data as a list
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

or

```
// Shows the data as a grid of two columns
int columns = 2;
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, columns));
```

The view and the adapter remain the same. The only thing that is changing is the way the data is presented to the user.

Comment: No. i am understanding it. i didnt get the concept of it. :-(

Comment: i am referring this -https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

Comment: where i have to write above two lines? After set adapter?

Comment: Try [this](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) tutorial. I'm sure you will get this understood after reading it. You are supposed to set the `LayoutManager` in the `onCreate()` method and in the callback listener `onClick()` method of the button.